# Database Replication or Mirroring?

Tags: sql-server-2005, replication

What is the difference between Replication and Mirroring in SQL server 2005?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In short, mirroring allows you to have a second server be a "hot" stand-by copy of the main server, ready to take over any moment the main server fails. So mirroring offers fail-over and reliability.

Replication, on the other hand, allows two or more servers to stay "in sync" - that means the secondary servers can answer queries and (depending on setup) actually change data (it will be merged in the sync). You can also use it for local caching, load balancing, etc.

Answer (score 5):

Mirroring is a feature that creates a copy of your database at bit level. Basically you have the same, identical, database in two places. You cannot optionally leave out parts of the database. You can have only one mirror, and the 'mirror' is always offline (it cannot be modified). Mirroring works by shipping the database log as is being created to the mirror and apply (redo-ing) the log on the mirror. Mirroring is a technology for high availability and disaster recoverability.

Replication is a feature that allow 'slices' of a database to be replicated between several sites. The 'slice' can be a set of database objects (ie. tables) but it can also contain parts of a table, like only certain rows (horizontal slicing) or only certain columns to be replicated. You can have multiple replicas and the 'replicas' are available to query and even can be updated. Replication works by tracking/detecting changes (either by triggers or by scanning the log) and shipping the changes, as T-SQL statements, to the subscribers (replicas). Replication is a technology for making data available at off sites and to consolidate data to central sites. Although it is sometimes used for high availability or for disaster recoverability, it is an artificial use for a problem that mirroring and log shipping address better.

There are several types and flavours of replication (merge, transactional, peer-to-peer etc.) and they differ in how they implement change tracking or update propagation, if you want to know more details you should read the [MSDN spec on the subject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151198(SQL.90).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Database mirroring is used to increase database uptime and reliability.

Replication is used primarily to distribute portions of your primary database -- the publisher -- to one or more subscriber databases.  This is often done to make data available (typically for read only) on remote servers so that remote clients can access the data locally (to them) rather than directly from the publisher across a slower WAN connection.  Although, as the previous posts indicate, there are more complex scenarios where updates are permitted on the subscribers.  It also can have the benefit of reducing the I/O load on the publisher.