# SQL Mirroring VS SQL Replication

Tags: sql-server, database-replication, failover, database-mirroring

I have two database instances. One of them hosted on web server and the other is a local instance. I need to synchronize data between them on time. Any transaction run on the web instance must run on the local instance too.
I searched on this subject and I am not sure if I should use replication (merge replication) or mirroring.

Comment: Have you tried exploring and trying to learn something yourself? I'm sure there are already some answers on this. Futhermore, this question is not in the format that questions should be asled here. For more information see the FAQ section. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/924252/database-replication-or-mirroring

Answer (score 2):

Database mirroring is to make a single database highly available.  This feature will be going away in SQL Server as microsoft is pushing people towards their "AlwaysOn" solution for high availability.

If you simply want the same transactions applied to a different database, I would recommend Transactional Replication.  This uses a log-reader agent to distribute transactions from the "publisher" to "subscriber" databases.  From your short description, this sounds like what you need.

Comment: thanks for help , just question the local instance must have static IP?

Comment: No on needing a static IP - as long as the name resolves correctly, this would be preferred - more detail here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151176.aspx